# Office365 connect to office button not working for Microsoft Teams. Getting 500 error

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I had created an **Office365** Connector for my Microsoft Teams app. Earlier it was working perfect, I was getting notifications in my channel.
Now it has stopped working. I am getting "Something went wrong" error with message "An unexpected error has occurred".  [something went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlsrw.png)
Any help regarding this would be appreciated. I am really stuck.

Manifest content :
{
    "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.0",
    "version": "1.1",
    "id": "8471589f-f521-4d69-8d59-6a207b9e1b7b",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.corrus",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Corrus",
        "websiteUrl": "https://corrus.com/",
        "privacyUrl": "https://corrus.com/terms/",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://corrus.com/terms/"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "corrus_logo.png",
        "outline": "corrus_logo_outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Corrus",
        "full": "Corrus"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "A work management platform to work collaboratively and accomplish goals.",
        "full": "Corrus is a work management tool for small teams to collaborate and manage projects in a cloud application. You can create tasks, build workflows and work with different stakeholders in one workspace. It helps teams align their processes and scale better as it enables them to break their goals and work into manageable blocks, create an action plan or a workflow, increase productivity and gain visibility within the team."
    },
    "accentColor": "#8170FF",
    "configurableTabs": [
        {
            "configurationUrl": "https://app.corrus.com/#/tabsConfig",
            "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
            "scopes": [
                "team"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "connectors": [
        {
            "connectorId": "8471589f-f521-4d69-8d59-6a207b9e1b7b",
            "scopes": [
                "team"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "app.corrus.com",
        "corrus.com"
    ]
}

Comment: I was able to add your connector without any issue. Could you pelase try adding the same connector on the some other Team which was created earlier? Please let us know.

Comment: I don't have any team which was created earlier. I have deleted all such teams.  Why can't I add my connector to newly created team ? Earlier I was able to add connector to newly created teams. Please suggest.

Comment: I am still not able to add connector to newly created team. Can I get clarification on it. I have submitted my Teams App to app store, they have rejected app because they are not able to configure tab.  Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue when we try to configure connector for newly created team. This issue has been fixed.

Note: Adding this as answer from comments section for visibility.